# How to get exchange rate with GoogleFinance on dates market is closed

Tags: google-finance, google-finance-api

I can retrieve the exchange rate on a given date with the following command:

```
=GoogleFinance("audusd","price","09/15/2015")
```

However if the market is closed that day then `GoogleFinance` returns "N/A":

```
=GoogleFinance("audusd","price","11/19/2015")
```

How do I get GoogleFinance to get me the price even though the market is closed?

Comment: Is getting the price on the last day it was open an option? Because then you could substract a day from your date until the value is no longer N/A

Comment: Yeah, that would be an option if the market is not open. The dates are coming in from another cell so some date are valid and some are invalid. How do I do what you suggested?

Comment: Are you using this inside Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: @DavidBrossard how do I do what you recommended?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following solution based on the UTC time:

```
import datetime as dt

nowUTC = dt.datetime.utcnow()                  
    today14= nowUTC.replace(hour=14, minute=25, second=0, microsecond=0)
    today21= nowUTC.replace(hour=21, minute=5, second=0, microsecond=0)

if (nowUTC >= today21 or today14 >= nowUTC):
```

This solution is based on the times at which the market is closed:

http://www.wisestockbuyer.com/2012/05/what-time-do-stock-markets-open-and-close/